# Adding Back icon and "Back" text within a UINavigationItem button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationitem, navigationitem

I have a button that i want it have the < back icon and also back text to it . This is what i did:

```
Text("\(Image(systemName: "chevron.left"))Back")
```

I am getting this error:

Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Image' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'

I tried fixing it as :

```
Text("\(Image(systemName: "chevron.left"))Back" as String)
```

But it does not work. How can i fix it .

Comment: maybe the problem is somewhere, not that image, I tried and it works
`Text("\(Image(systemName: "chevron.left")) Back")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a back button like this:

```
Button(action: {
    
}, label: {
    HStack(spacing: 4) {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
        Text("Back")
    }
})
.accentColor(.blue)
```

However, I would note that if you are using a NavigationView and are segueing with a NavigationLink, the back button will automatically be there and you do not need to recreate it.